# Cómo hacer dentro de una promise un for y dentro del for una promise por cada vuelta en NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, promesas

Hola y gracias por vuestro tiempo. Soy principiante en NodeJS y el problema que tengo es el siguiente. Tengo una api rest con nodeJS y express, para conectarme a sql server utilizo el paquete [mssql](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql). En uno de los endpoints realizo una consulta a la bdd mediante una promise. El resultado de esta promise me devuelve varias filas y cada una de estas filas contiene un ID. Por cada ID tengo que hacer otra consulta y obtener más datos pero debo hacerlo de forma síncrona ya que sinó se ejecuta código que debería ejecutarse tras terminar todo el bloque for. Dejo el código.

```
    router.get('/messages', verifyToken, function (req, res) {
    const web = req.web;
    const email = req.email;

    let response = new Object()

    sql.connect(configDB).then(() => {
        return sql.query`SELECT p.chat_id as id FROM PARTICIPANT p INNER JOIN XW_USUARIOS u ON p.USER_ID = u.IDENTI where u.email = ${email}`
    }).then(result => {

        return result.recordsets[0] // Contiene los ID

    }).then(chatIds => {

        let chats = []

        // Por cada vuelta necesito llamar a la base de datos y no puede haber un callback ya que sinó lo realiza de forma asíncrona y se ejecuta el código de los otros "then" antes de terminar este.
        for (let index = 0; index < chatIds.length; index++) {
            const chat = chatIds[index]; // Obtenemos el ID del chat actual.

            const request = new sql.Request()
            request.input('chatId', sql.Int, chat.id)

            // Aquí debería haber una promise por cada vuelta del bucle for. Cada vuelta debería ir llenando el array chats o devolver los datos a añadir en el array.
            chats = request.query('select u.email, u.usuario as username from xw_usuarios u INNER JOIN participant p ON u.identi = p.user_id WHERE p.chat_id = @chatId', (err, result2) => {

                if (err === null)
                    sendError(res, err)

                let users = [] // Array de usuarios.

                result2.recordset.forEach(userData => {
                    let user = new Object() // Objeto usuario que contendrá el email y su nombre.
                    user.email = userData.email
                    user.username = userData.username
                    users.push(user) // Añadimos el usuario al array de usuarios.
                });

                chat.users = users // Añadimos el array de usuarios dentro del chat actual.

                chats.push(chat) 

                return chats

            })

        }

        return chats

    }).then(chats => {

        /* ... más código .... */
        res.json(chats) // Devolvemos la respuesta.
        sql.close() // Cerramos la conexión con la base de datos.

    }).catch(err => {
        sendError(res, err)
    })
})
```

Espero haberme explicado claramente, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que uses las promesas de Node, lo que puedes hacer es un map para obtener un array de promesas y hacer un Promise.all().

```
.then(chatIds => {

    const chatPromises = chatIds.map((chatId) => {
        const request = new sql.Request();
        request.input('chatId', sql.Int, chatId);

        // Aquí buscas el chat en la base de datos, pero lo metes en un array de promesas.
        return request.query('select u.email, u.usuario as username from xw_usuarios u INNER JOIN participant p ON u.identi = p.user_id WHERE p.chat_id = @chatId');
    });

    return Promise.all(chatPromises);
}).then(chats => {
    // Aquí ya puedes trabajar con los chats que has recuperado de la base de datos.
});
```

Comment: Genial, justo lo que necesitaba. Solo me ha dado un pequeño problema y es que en el elemento chatId del map hay que acceder al atributo chatId.id para pasarle a la query. ¡Mil gracias!